# How to detect if a key is being held down

Tags: python

I am using getkey to detect key presses, how do I do while key is down, and if so then how do I break it with another key press?

Comment: What is getkey?

Comment: You mean this package that hasn't been updated in 5+ years? https://pypi.org/project/getkey/

Comment: Use a different package: getkey doesn't provide information about the current state of the keyboard.

Comment: Keyboard doesn’t work on replit

Comment: Replit a browser IDE